# Heroku -- push not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So I used `heroku create` with one of my apps, but then when on heroku.com I deleted the corresponding repository.  I tried using `heroku create` again and it did give me another URL, but now when I try to push my app it keeps looking for the old one:

```
!  No such app as [old name]
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How do I get heroku to stop looking for this old app and use the newly created one?

Comment: [old name] is the old URL of my app which I deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your local git repository has the old URL saved in its `heroku` remote. You have to update it using

```
git remote set-url --push heroku git@heroku.com:new_app.git
```

See [Heroku's documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#git_remotes_and_heroku) and the [Git manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) for more information.